# Tagging feature not working

Tags: 2010, tagging

The "I like It" and "Tags & Notes" buttons in the ribbon are grayed out and "currently disabled", 
on my SP2010 site.I don't know how to enable them.

Also I am not using active directory but FBA system.

So can someone suggest how to enable tagging?

Answer (score 2):

Check: 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721063.aspx

and/or:
http://blog.beckybertram.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=101

Specifically, the "Use social features" must be enabled, in order for tagging to be enabled (not 100% sure whether the buttons will actually be disabled or hidden, when "use social features=false", so you will need to verify this for yourself.)

Answer (score 1):

You must have the User Profile Service running and a MySite

Comment: How to get User Profile Service running?